# How to edit attribute of element in last row of table?

Tags: php, html-table

I have a table on my [site](http://ksa-flight-tracker.tk/dunai) which is from another site. As you can see there are links on the PREV/NEXT buttons, how can I change these to something else? I know I can use

[A Element]->setAttribute('href',[LINK]) but how would I get [A Element]. Also the table doesn't always have the same number of rows.

Answer (score 2):

The PREV/NEXT buttons are actually images that include the words PREV and NEXT, so you'd have to replace those images if you wanted to use a different word.

Comment: I dont, I want to replace the link

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like you'll just have to go back and edit the HTML markup. On all of your pages, the NEXT image is not wrapped in an `<a>` tag. You can manipulate/fix this with Javascript, but you'd be better off editing the HTML if possible.

Comment: I can't edit the HTML as the table is brought straight from another sight with PHP. Also the next only doesn't have a link as it is the last record. If you pressed Prev, then you would be able to press Next to go forward.